# I can't get a photographic image to map to a train wheel

Tags: uv, transparency

I've been struggling to learn blender for a year, and it's finally all coming together but for one problem. A toy train features prominently, and every thing llooks great except for the wheels. I can get them looking bright, but not mettalic. I just found the perfect photo on a white backround, but I can't even make the backround transparent in gimp. I need to texture map it to the wheels, and I don't think the node editor is going to cut it. Uv mapping is my last unlearned skill.Any help would be greatly appreciated.
K

Comment: I personally found this guide very useful when I was learning UV mapping - https://artisticrender.com/the-definitive-tutorial-to-uv-mapping-in-blender/

Comment: Hello, some screenshots of your reference image and of your 3D object would help, maybe even share them both: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: To remove the white background in Gimp it's the **Layer** menu > **Transparency** > **Color to Alpha**. It's probably not necessary to do that and if done then it would probably be best to add a layer beneath and give it some kind of .. grey color to match the color of the wheels. As Moonboots has already suggested we need to at least see both the wheels geometry and image, best is to copy and paste a wheel into a new .blend and edit your question to include it using the link he provided. Maybe simpler to use a metalic shader ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cTZW6Xy7v0